# Targeting Multiple Devices using Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am developing website that targeting on phones, tablets and desktops. Let's say i have a div element. What is the good way to handle these devices, should i have 3 different version of codes or maybe i just have to include all the class in one div like this :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Content</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like your example, with Bootstrap you can use the multiple `col-*` classes in a single DIV. The **smaller grid classes *also* apply to larger screens** unless overriden specifically for larger screens. Therefore, you *only* need to use the class for the *smallest device width* you want to support. Smaller widths than 768 pixels always stack vertically (12 columns) unless you use the `xs` classes

- xs - for less that 768 px
- sm - for 768 px and greater
- md - for 992 px and greater
- lg - for 1200 px and greater

Examples...

**12 columns wide on *all* devices:**
(you don't need `sm`,`md`,`lg` unless you want different widths on each device)

```
<div class="col-xs-12">Content</div>
```

**6 columns wide on desktop(lg), laptop(md), tablet(sm), 12 columns on phone(xs):**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">Content</div>
```

**6 columns wide on on *all* devices:**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">Content</div>
```

**4 columns on lg and md, 6 cols on sm and xs:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">Content</div>
```

**Demo with more examples:** 
http://www.bootply.com/73778

Answer (score 0):

Prepare ur website for Desktop and use this metatags.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 , maximum-scale=1.0">
```

col-xs-12 is to make content get fitted for one single row. Bootstrap makes ur content to fit in different devices automatically when u include bootstrap.css in ur project.